# How to remove the bottom navigation bar in a TWA?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I have build a TWA as described at https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa

I want to remove the bottom navigation bar. I have read that it can only be done programmatically with IMMERSIVE mode : https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

So i need to add a Class associated to the activity "android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity" and to add the hideSystemUI() code in onCreate() i guess.

How to do that ?

Here is the manifest :

```
....
<activity
    android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.LauncherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
....
```

How to code the immersive mode for this activity ?

Comment: There's currently an open bug to implement this feature: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=965329

Answer (score 1):

### Using Bubblewrap

When using [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/tree/master/packages/cli) (recommended), you will be asked which display mode the application should use as part of the `init` command.

If you have already initialized the application, modify `twa-manifest.json`, set `display` to `fullscreen`.

### In AndroidManifest.xml

When building the application yourself and using the default `LauncherActivity`, you can get set the following meta-tag as part of the Activity definition in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
 <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DISPLAY_MODE"
                android:value="immersive" />
```